# How can i select distinct using one field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

How can i select `distinct()` based on one field?

I have the following LINQ expression, how can I select distinct by ID field. for some reason i used `.Distinct()` but keeps shown me a duplicate, I want to show just one record

```
 var customersbyName = await _context.vw_CustomerSearch.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(request.searchWord))   
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var customersbyName = await _context.vw_CustomerSearch.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(request.searchWord))
                            .Select(c => c.ID)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct compare each column of the row, so if one column is different, the row is distinct for linq / sql.

You can try it with a GroupBy:

```
var customersbyName = await _context.vw_CustomerSearch.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(request.searchWord))
  .GroupBy(i => i.ID)
  .Select(x => x.First())
```